# Send parameter to controller via Laravel Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Given the following code, I simple want the second route to send an arbitrary value for id or any other variable I can access from within `show()`;

```
Route::get('foo/{id}', 'FoobarController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('bar', 'FoobarController@show')->with('id', -1);    // This pseudo-code doesn't work. I want to send parameter id with an arbitrary value
```

Comment: You might just want to conditional call a method from within your controller after you check the value of id

Comment: But in the second route how do I actually send the value of the id?

Comment: As a null able variable {id?}

Comment: Have you tried in controller `show` method as an extra parameter named `id` something link this `public function show($id=0){}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this?

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('bar/{id?}', 'FoobarController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

**Controller:**

```
class FoobarController extends Controller{
    public function show($id){
        $id = $id ? $id : "default value";
    }
}
```

*Or:*

```
public function show($id="default value"){..}
```